# How to open a hyperlink from a cell reference?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have attempted to change the below code so that the webpage that is opened, is from the URL that is pasted into a specific cell; C5 from the sheet entitled 'Main page'. This is required as the URL will be changing frequently.

Previously the code was `.navigate2 "www.example.com"`.

Now, I have inserted `".MainPage.Range("c5").Hyperlinks(1).Follow"` into the code in an attempt to open the URL from the specified cell.

However this returned the following error:

> Run-time'438'error - Object doesn't support this property or method.

Is this a result of IE not being able to initially identify this URL? Any ideas on how to make this function appropriately are most welcome.

```
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As Object, hTable As HTMLTable, clipboard As Object, ws1 As Worksheet, MainPage As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Margin Comparison")
    Set MainPage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Run VBA")
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        MainPage.Range("c4").Hyperlinks(1).Follow

        With .document
            If .querySelectorAll(".offer-close").Length > 0 Then .querySelector(".offer-close").Click
            .querySelector(".tools-icon").Click
            If .querySelectorAll("[title='Change to decimal odds']").Length > 0 Then .querySelector("[title='Change to decimal odds']").Click
        End With
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set hTable = .document.querySelector(".eventTable")
        clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ws1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        Dim cutOff As Range
        Set cutOff = ws1.Columns(1).Find("QuickBet")
        If Not cutOff Is Nothing Then ws1.Rows("1:" & cutOff.Row).EntireRow.Delete
    .Quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainPage` is not a property of `ie`

```
.MainPage.Range("c5").Hyperlinks(1).Follow
```

should be

```
MainPage.Range("c5").Hyperlinks(1).Follow
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment; understood. 

However, will this not impact the subsequent code onwards from:

with.document ?

Comment: No it will only affect that one line where you remove the leading period.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tim. I have edited the code above to reflect the changes. 

That being said, the following error is returned in relation to the 'with.document' portion of code:-

'Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Following a hyperlink doesn't necessarily use the IE object you just created.  You should switch back to the Navigate method.   `.navigate2 MainPage.Range("c4").Value`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Sheets("Main page").Range("C5").Hyperlinks(1).Follow
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Excel are you using? I have tried to test the following code in Excel 2016, everything works well, you could try to create a new worksheet and test the following code again: (In my sample, I create a worksheet named "Main Page", then add a link in the C5 cell)

```
Dim ie As Object, MainPage As Worksheet
Set MainPage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Page")
MainPage.Range("c5").Hyperlinks(1).Follow
```

Besides, you could also try to get the cell hyperlink address first, then, using the Navigate method to direct to the web site. Code as below:

```
Dim ie As Object, MainPage As Worksheet

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set MainPage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Page")

ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate MainPage.Range("c5").Hyperlinks(1).Address
```